# Generate Excel of php array using php-spreadsheets

Tags: php

I am trying to generate excel of .txt file using PHP-spreadsheets first I am  creating array of .txt data than I'll be writing .txt data into excel using php-spreadsheets my excel is getting generated but while opening that excel I am getting below error message

> Excel cannot open the file because file-format or extension is not valid verify the file that it has not been corrupted and the file extension matches the format of the file

```
 $lines = array();
 $fopen = fopen('read.txt', 'r');
 while (!feof($fopen)) {
     $line=fgets($fopen);
     $line=trim($line);
     $lines[]=$line;
 
 }
 fclose($fopen);
 $finalOutput = array();
 foreach ($lines as $string)
 {
     $string = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $string);
     $row = explode(" ", $string);
     array_push($finalOutput,$row);
 }
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($finalOutput);
 echo "</pre>";
 
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv;
 
 $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
 $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

 $sheet->fromArray($finalOutput, NULL, 'A1');     
 
 // redirect output to client browser
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xlsx"');
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
 
 $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
 $writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: use statements and require should be on top of the script.

Comment: Try removing use of xls, and csv as it is unused. Does it work if you write to a file instead?

Comment: Is this all supposed to be one single script file? Then you are obviously invalidating your excel data by outputting `echo "<pre>"; print_r($finalOutput); echo "</pre>";` before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please delete / remark all data output statements from your script before the headers for generating the xlsx file. Remember that header() should be called before any actual output is sent. You may refer to the following link (official documentation) :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

(1) Hence, please remark the following 3 lines

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalOutput);
echo "</pre>";
```

(2) OPTIONAL - On the other hand, for your case if there is no need to use xls and csv, tyen remark these two lines as well

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv;
```

So change to

```
<?php

 $lines = array();
 $fopen = fopen('read.txt', 'r');
 while (!feof($fopen)) {
     $line=fgets($fopen);
     $line=trim($line);
     $lines[]=$line;
 
 }
 fclose($fopen);
 $finalOutput = array();
 foreach ($lines as $string)
 {
     $string = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $string);
     $row = explode(" ", $string);
     array_push($finalOutput,$row);
 }
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($finalOutput);
// echo "</pre>";
 
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
 //use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;
 //use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv;
 
 $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
 $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();


 $sheet->fromArray($finalOutput, NULL, 'A1');     
 
 // redirect output to client browser
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xlsx"');
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
 
 $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
 $writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: I want to generate  excel 3 formats which is csv,xls,xlsx

Comment: no problems then just do point 1 and ignore point 2 which is optional

Comment: MY all excel fields is going into A1 , perhaps I have only given reference of A1 that's why do you have any suggestion how can i spilt up my columns into A1,B1,C1